# Pass canvas.toDataURL("image/bmp") from Javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, post, html5-canvas

I want to POST dataURL from canvas to my servlet using Javascript or Ajax. Since my canvas has higher resolution and more data, it is not possible to send dataURL as normal request parameter. I already tried to do that by encoding dataURL with `encodeURIComponent(myUrl)`. But it is ended up with 400 error.

Comment: Browser matters here. Canvas implementations differ a lot on image handling.

Comment: Why do you use "image/bmp"? BMP is an uncompressed format which makes it very large. Try "image/png" or "image/jpeg". They should result in much smaller dataURLs.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp, actually I'm using image/png. Also I tried with image/jpeg. But had no any luck. So I converted data url into byte array and send 5kb segments at single time using ajax calls. I did it in that way. But its really not efficient.